# Horizontal alignment: Function and a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the following table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
$x$ & $-4$ & $0$ & $4$ & $12$ \\ \hline
$P_X(x)$ & $\frac{1}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{6}$ & $\frac{1}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{3}$ \\ \hline
$F_X(x)$ & $\frac{1}{4}$ & $\frac{5}{12}$ & $\frac{2}{3}$ & $1$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and the following function:

```
$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{für \phantom{a}}x < -4,\\
1/4&\text{für \phantom{a}}-4 \leq x < 0,\\
5/12&\text{für \phantom{a}}0 \leq x < 4, \\
2/3&\text{für \phantom{a}}4 \leq x < 12, \\
1&\text{für \phantom{a}} x \geq 12. \\
\end{cases}$$
```

They look like this:

[image: table]

[image: function]

What I want is: [Table] $\Rightarrow$ [Function], so that they are next to each other (horizontally). How can I do this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just  `[Table] $\Rightarrow [Function]$` works, but [Table] is not the `table` float environment, but only the ***tabular*** environment.

Comment: @Fran Where do I put this? Can you please show it my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\[\begin{array}{c|cccc}
x & -4 & 0 & 4 & 12 \\ \hline
P_X(x) & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{3} \\ \hline
F_X(x) & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{5}{12} & \frac{2}{3} & 1
\end{array}
\Rightarrow F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{für \phantom{a}}x < -4,\\
1/4&\text{für \phantom{a}}-4 \leq x < 0,\\
5/12&\text{für \phantom{a}}0 \leq x < 4, \\
2/3&\text{für \phantom{a}}4 \leq x < 12, \\
1&\text{für \phantom{a}} x \geq 12. \\
\end{cases}\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!